# Having a clickable background div but excluding foreground divs

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a page where I have to make the background be a clickable link, whilst having the foreground works okay. I managed to get the background clickable this way:

```
<div id="site_background_container" onclick="window.location.href='{{$background_link}}'" style="position:relative; z-index:-100; cursor:pointer;">

<div id="site_main_container" style="z-index:5;">
```

The problem is that now the `site_main_container` div is also clickable. How can I limit the click-ability to only `site_background_container`?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery. If the `e.target` is the same element as this, you've not clicked on a descendant.

```
$('#site_background_container').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this) {
    return;
  }
  alert('clicked the site_background_container');
});
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
$('#site_background_container').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this) {
    return;
  }
  alert('clicked the site_background_container');
});
```

```css
#site_background_container {
  background: #ff0;
  padding: 20px;
}

#site_main_container {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="site_background_container">
  <div id="site_main_container" style="z-index:5;">
    Site Main Container
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!