# Prevent onClick from firing if another element is on top

Tags: javascript, html

I have an app in which something happens when you click the background, however, I don't want it to activate if you click on something else that is on top of the background. For example:

```js
function handleClick() {
  alert("Hello!");
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onClick="handleClick()">
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

In this example, how can I prevent the alert from displaying when the user clicks on the green box?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000403/having-a-clickable-background-div-but-excluding-foreground-divs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the event to the function, and check whether its target is the same as the element itself. When you click on an inner element, the target will be that element. Use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling out to the container.

```js
function handleClick(event, element) {
  if (event.target != element) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    return;
  }
  alert("Hello!");
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onClick="handleClick(event, this)">
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use inside div `onclick="event.stopPropagation()"`

**Stopping Bubbling**

A [bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) event goes from the target element straight up. Normally it goes upwards till `<html>`, and then to `document` object, and some events even reach `window`, calling all handlers on the path.

But any handler may decide that the event has been fully processed and stop the bubbling.

The method for it is [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

**DEMO**

```js
function handleClick() {
  alert("Hello!");
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onClick="handleClick()">
  <div onclick="event.stopPropagation()" class="button"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare `e.target` against `e.currentTarget` like this:

```js
function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target == e.currentTarget) {
    alert("Hello!");
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onClick="handleClick(event)">
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd detach the event handler when that "something" appears over the top:

```
element.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown, true);
```

(Note the last argument must match the "useCapture" value when you created the event.)

or in your case:

```
document.getElementById('yourDiv').onclick = null;
```

or

```
document.getElementById("yourDiv").removeAttribute("onClick");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added the `handleClick` function on the div that **(class="container")** covered the screen.
when you click anywhere handleClick will run.
So add that function the div that has **class= "button"**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="button" onClick="handleClick()">
</div>
```